# How do I implement entity coreferencing for company name data?

Tags: nlp, data-cleaning

I have data with a column vector of company names as such:

```
Var1
AEP
American Electric Power
AEP - Ohio
Chase Bank
JP Morgan
Chase
```

I am trying to figure out how to resolve the coreferences in this dataset. I have been trying to figure out how to use Wikipedia miner to solve this problem, but I don't know how it works or how to use it. Does there exist a tool that can find instances of different names that relate to the same company?

In other words, I would like to merge similar names of the same company (e.g. AEP, American Electric Power, and AEP - Ohio are all one company and so is Chase Bank, Chase, and JP Morgan). The column has over 41,000 unique number of companies.

Comment: Can you clarify your question? What you want is to merge similar names in that list of companie names? For instance: AEP with AEP - Ohio, and Chase Bank with Chase?

Also, how big is your dataset, i.e., how many company names are in that column?

Comment: Thank you, David. I will get to editing it now.

Comment: I don't think the name you used to describe the task is correct. I think its more duplicate merging, or data cleaning task. Entity co-referencing is another thing, e.g.: "Bill said he would come" the proper noun Bill and the pronoun he refer to the same person, namely to Bill; this is a well-known task in NLP, which explores syntactic relationship that exists between coreferential expressions in sentences and texts. What you want to do is different from this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use one of the existing Knowledge graphs such as

- [DBpedia](http://wiki.dbpedia.org/)
- [YAGO3](https://www.mpi-inf.mpg.de/departments/databases-and-information-systems/research/yago-naga/yago/): Entity names are attached to relations  (not sure) and rdf:label
- [BabelNet](http://babelnet.org/) : only an API

Also, if you are interested just in the possible names of an Entity, check [AIDA](https://www.mpi-inf.mpg.de/departments/databases-and-information-systems/research/yago-naga/aida/) It is an opensource java Named Entity Disambiguation (similar to Wikipedia miner). You can use there dataset only as it has set of possible names and context phrases for each Entity. The English resource is rich.

Entities can be filtered using typing system.

Answer (score 0):

You have 41.000 unique companies and you want to merge
all the similar names. I believe you need to do two things:

- devise a similarity function to compare any two given company names
- find an efficient way to compare all the names in your dateset

For the similarity metric, and taking into consideration the small sample you provided I notice 3 different types of names:

1. Acronyms: 'AEP' is an acronym for 'American Electric Power'
2. Single-Token names: 'Chase'
3. Multi-Token names: 'American Electric Power'

I believe your metric has to take these into consideration, I will give you
some suggestions at the end of my post.

To make an efficient comparison I would suggest the [Sorted Neighborhood Method](http://hpi.de/fileadmin/user_upload/fachgebiete/naumann/folien/SS13/DPDC/DPDC_14_SNM.pdf) approach, which has 3 steps:

1. Create a sorting key: Define a key based on the companies names, which can be simple the first letter of first string of the name, or it can be something more complex made of sub-strings from the companies names;
2. Sort data: The names are sorted by using the key defined in the first step;
3. Merge: A fixed size window is moved through the sequential list of names in order to limit the comparisons for matching records to those records in the window. If the size of the window is w, then every new name that enters that window is compared with the previous w-1 names to find "matching" names.

For instance, suppose your key is defined by the first letter of the first string, your list would be ordered like this:

```
AEP
American Electric Power
AEP - Ohio
Chase Bank
Chase
JP Morgan
```

now using a window of size 3 to make the comparison, you would first only compare:

```
AEP
American Electric Power
AEP - Ohio
```

If your similarity function takes into consideration acronyms, it would find out that AEP is an acronym for American Electric Power, and merge the two. You can now keep both strings as a representation of the same company name or just choose one, imagine you keep both:

```
['AEP, 'American Electric Power']
AEP - Ohio
Chase Bank
```

Now you compare 'AEP - Ohio' with  ['AEP', 'American Electric Power'], again depending on how you define your function this could be a match, for instance, you can see the overlap of 'AEP - Ohio' with 'AEP' which would give 0.5 (i.e., assuming you discarded the '-'), plus you could also check that in 'AEP - Ohio' there is a sequence that is an acronym for 'American Electric Power'.

```
['AEP', 'American Electric Power','AEP - Ohio'] 
Chase Bank
Chase
```

Now comparing the next one should give now match and we advance the window:

```
Chase Bank
Chase
JP Morgan
```

Your similarity function here should match 'Chase' and 'Chase Bank'. At the end,
you would have:

```
['AEP', 'American Electric Power', 'AEP - Ohio']
['Chase Bank', 'Chase']
JP Morgan
```

Note, there many [algorithms to estimate string similarity](http://web.archive.org/web/20081224234350/http://www.dcs.shef.ac.uk/~sam/stringmetrics.html), here you have Python and Java libraries that implement some of them:

- http://www.chokkan.org/software/simstring/
- https://github.com/seatgeek/fuzzywuzzy
- http://secondstring.sourceforge.net/

For detecting the acronyms I would suggest [A Simple Algorithm for Identifying Abbreviation Definitions in Biomedical Text](http://biotext.berkeley.edu/papers/psb03.pdf) by A.S Schwartz and M.A. Hearst. The Java implementation is available [here](http://biotext.berkeley.edu/code/abbrev/). I applied this algorithm to the English Wikipedia, you can see the results [here](https://github.com/davidsbatista/lexicons/blob/master/wikipedia-acronyms.txt).